# PHP Eval alternative to include a file

Tags: php, gearman, beanstalkd

I am currently running a queue system with beanstalk + supervisor + PHP.

I would like my workers to automatically die when a new version is available (basically code update).

My current code is as follow

```
class Job1Controller extends Controller
{
public $currentVersion = 5;

public function actionIndex()
{
    while (true) {
        // check if a new version of the worker is available
        $file = '/config/params.php';
        $paramsContent = file_get_contents($file);
        $params = eval('?>' . file_get_contents($file));
        if ($params['Job1Version'] != $this->currentVersion) {
            echo "not the same version, exit worker \n";
            sleep(2);
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "same version, continue processing \n";
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I will update the code, the params file will change with a new version number which will force the worker to terminate. I cannot use include as the file will be loaded in memory in the while loop. Knowing that the file params.php isn't critical in terms of security I wanted to know if there was another way of doing so?

Edit: the params.php looks as follow:

```
<?php
return [
'Job1Version' => 5
];
```

Comment: Assuming `params.php` is just a bunch of variables, you could use ini, json or a similar serialization format.

Comment: Serializing your config (json or serialize) is (much) faster than an include, and definitely faster than read and eval. JSON is even readable and editable. Just sayin.

Comment: Using an ini file just to keep workers' versions could indeed be a solution as the code will be executed a large amount of time in a day and I am guessing that using parse_ini would be still faster than eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few tests I finally managed to find a solution which doesn't require versionning anymore.

```
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($this);
$lastUpdatedTimeOnStart = filemtime($reflectionClass->getFileName());

while (true) {
    clearstatcache();
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($this);
    $lastUpdatedTime = filemtime($reflectionClass->getFileName());
    if ($lastUpdatedTime != $lastUpdatedTimeOnStart) {
        // An update has been made, exit
    } else {
       // worker hasn't been modified since running
    }
}
```

Whenever the file will be updated, the worker will automatically exit 
Thanks to @Rudie who pointed me into the right direction.

Comment: But where do you get the params? That was the intention wasn't it? Get the new params when they've been changed?

Comment: The main purpose was to check whenever a new version of the worker was released and exit it to run the new version. In the beginning I thought that having a version for each worker was the only solution but relying on the params means that everytime I update the worker I will have to update its version in the file. Relying on filemtime is actually more flexible as it doesn't require me to update these params as the code will automatically check if the worker has been modified since its has been running. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = require($file);
```

Since your file has a `return` statement, the returned value will be passed along.

Comment: Using require will not catch an update of the params.php file due to the while loop.

Comment: Huh, PHP caches includes... You can do them multiple times, but they'll be the same every time. Didn't know that. `clearstatcache()` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Rudie Actually I have been running a couple of tests and found a better automated solution that doesn't require versionning anymore.
In the Job1Controller I am calling:
    clearstatcache();
    $reflectionClass new \ReflectionClass($this)
    $lastUpdated = filemtime($reflectionClass->getFileName());
And compare the value with the value defined on run. 
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.